# Funcion con OUT VARCHAR2

Tags: sql, oracle-sqldeveloper

Estoy intentando ejecutar una función que esta en un paquete pero me devuelve un error.
[image: Error]

La función es de este tipo

[image: función]

Creo que mi error viene al no saber que valor darle al Out Varchar2, yo lo estoy ejecutando de esta manera

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

He probado múltiples combinaciones pero no consigo dar con la solución.

Muchas gracias

Comment: Por favor, [no publiques imágenes con código fuente](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2869/21), copia y pega directamente el código en tu pregunta. NO olvides incluir de la misma manera mensajes exactos de error. Un saludo.

Answer (score 1):

Los procedimientos de base de datos en Oracle permiten que definas el tipo de dato que es, si es de entrada, de salida o de entrada salida.

Los parámetros de entrada se pueden pasar directamente a través de una constante, pero como parámetros de salida hay que pasar una variable para que pueda asignar el valor devuelto a ella.

En tu caso el error viene más o menos por donde tú comentas. Como te comento, debes pasar una variable al parámetro out para poder obtener este valor.

Si pruebas algo así te funcionará

```sql
DECLARE
 v_mivariable varchar2(500);
BEGIN
 pk_riesgos_ITE.RECALCULAR_RIESGO_CLIENTES('001','0900009','0900009','09','09',v_mivariable);
END;
```